# Run Java method inside build definition in SBT/Play

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

What I want in SBT is to have an input task that for `foo a b c` in the Play 2.2.1 console a call to a Java (static) method passing `a b c` as a list of arguments is executed.

PlayConsole: `foo a b c ===should call===> Foo.bar(a,b,c)`

I have the following play directory structure and files (Java project):

```
-myplayapp  
  -app  
    -controllers  
    -views  
    -myfolder
        Foo.java  
   -project  
     ...  
     build.scala
   ...
```

**myfolder.Foo**

```
package myfolder;

public class Foo {
    public static void bar(String... args) {
        for(String s : args)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**project/build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import sbt.complete.Parsers._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "myplayapp"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq()

    val foo = inputKey[Unit]("Foo you.")

    val fooSettings = foo := {    
        val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed          
        // Foo.bar(args)
    }

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        fooSettings    
    )
}
```

I have tried `import myfolder.Foo._` and `import myfolder.Foo.bar` with no success. The error is the same for both cases:

```
not found: object myfolder.
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: The problem is not with `static`. This works fine: `import java.lang.String.format; format("a %s c", "b")`

Comment: Why don't you make a scala method in build.scala instead? `def foo(args: String*): Unit = args.foreach(println)` or something or any expression for that matter.

Comment: You can use Setup, Cleanup steps on Compile, Test, etc and plug this method in.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov well...I only know Java and I read that Java and Scala are interoperable. I just wanna know how to do this.

Comment: I might be wrong but you would have to compile the Java class separately and make it visible on SBT classpath. SBT can compile Java classes of the source code and then compile Scala classes that use them. However I've never seen such functionality. Maybe it's there.

Comment: I tried to compile your class with javac and then import it in SBT and make it available with SBT classpath but SBT refuses to find it. Maybe there are ways to force it.

Comment: You can create your own plugin and use it with SBT but this seems like overkill perhaps. Just write it in Scala ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use Play 2.2.1 that comes with [sbt 0.13 support](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22) I'll use `build.sbt` instead. You should be able to migrate it to `ApplicationBuild` of yours with ease as the changes are rather *cosmetic*.

Create `build.sbt` in the project directory of the Play application with the following content:

```
import sbt.complete.Parsers._
import myfolder.Foo

lazy val foo = inputKey[Unit]("Foo you.")

foo := {
  val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  Foo.bar(args: _*)
}
```

Note that `import`'s don't need a new line in-between as well as `args` needs to be expanded to varargs with `_*`.

Save the following `Foo.java` file in `project/src/main/java/myfolder`.

**project/src/main/java/myfolder/Foo.java**

```
package myfolder;

public class Foo {
    public static void bar(String... args) {
        for(String s : args)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Please note that since you need to use the Java class in the build definition (be able to execute a task with parameters from SBT), it has to be part of the SBT build not your Play project (and hence it's under `project` - see [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive)).

When SBT shell's up, run the `foo` input task with any number of arguments:

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> foo2 ala ma kota
ala
ma
kota
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 21, 2014 12:00:46 AM
```

Comment: I was able to run the method inside the play console following your steps. I just created a `/src/main/java/myfolder/Foo.java` inside the `/myplayapp/project` and it worked. I don't know if it's the best playframework practice for what i needed to accomplish but i'll stick to it for now. Thank you Jacek.

Comment: I don't have much experience with SBT so I don't know whether it's a good practice or not. What I say in such situations is that regardless of any other options, if they're unknowns, the one we know is the best one. I can't seem to think of a better approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath of the sbt instance is not the same classpath as the one of your project. If it was then it would not be possible to start your project in sbt if you had a compilation error for example since it would create a dependency and the compiler would have to compile your project file first to be able to compile the Build.scala file.

To be able to use classes in sbt they would have to be among the builds sources, which is the classes that lives in the `project/` directory. If you put build-related java sources under project/ then sbt will compile those before running and you will be able to access those classes from the sbt build file.

(This makes it possible to define plugins specific to a project in sbt compared to for example maven where you have to make all plugins available as artifacts that can be resolved through the dependency system)